# Convex Hull Optimization Java

Tags: java, convex-optimization

I recently read the article from [PEG Wiki](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick) about the convex hull trick. Surprisingly, at the end of the article I read that we can achieve a fully [dynamic variant](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick#Fully_dynamic_variant) of the trick (meaning that there are no conditions of applicability) if we store the lines in a std::set. Although I have understood the approach mentioned, I always fail when I try to implement it.
In other words, there is an array A of size n, where each array element contains two positive integers ai and bi.
There are Q queries where each query can be one of two types:

1) Given a positive integer x, find `max (aix + bi)` for all i from 1 to n

2) Update values of ai and bi for some i. 
 Value to be updated will be in non-decreasing order i.e. `ai1>=ai2 and bi1>=bi2 for Q >= i1 > i2 >= 1`.
Update Part can be performed using by deleting previous line and adding a new line. I am looking both update and query part for amortized (log n) complexity in Java

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? We aren't going to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Actually, I found the same part of code here https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/convex_hull_optimization . But in this query x always ascends. In my question query may increase or decrease. In the given link its finding min(ax+b), I have to get max(ax+b). If you could explain me how to implement this, I will make the code

Comment: `Math.max(1,2)` will return 2, the maximum value of the two arguments

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I know that. But replacing `ptr = Math.min(ptr, len - 1)` with `ptr = Math.max(ptr, len - 1)` from the link given in comment will not give the correct answer.